# SQL query syntax error while creating a table

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I am getting a SQL query syntax error while creating a table. Here is the SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (
  ACCNO NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  BA L NUMBER(8,2) NOT NULL,
  CREATION-DT DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( ACCNO )
);
```

Here is the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'NUMBER(5) NOT NULL.

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: `Number` field type doesn't exist in SQL server, probably you mean `numeric`

Comment: this is also the case in MySQL

Comment: Are you a COBOL programmer?  I think it used `number` for picture statements.

Comment: Once that is fixed, the next problem will be the dash character in the column name **`CREATION-DT`**. In order to use the dash character in an identifier, the identifier will need to be escaped. The preferred pattern is to not use a dash character as part of a column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) you can see this is not valid.

You have multiple problems with your syntax; [invalid data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html), [invalid column names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html), etc. You can encapsulate the invalid names in backticks but then you will have to remember to encapsulate them later.

Instead of `Number` you probably meant `numeric` but i would suggest trying `Integer` instead.

Or just try this:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (
  ACCNO INTEGER(5) NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  BAL INTEGER(8) NOT NULL,
  CREATIONDT DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( ACCNO )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`NUMBER` is not a valid datatype in MySQL, you should choose the one from the [list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html) (*maybe you've meant `NUMERIC`*).

You should also escape some identifiers (in your case, column names `BA L`, which includes a space within it,  and `CREATION-DT`, which includes a dash) with backticks `` ` `` in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `ACCOUNT` (
  `ACCNO` NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `BA L` NUMERIC(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `CREATION-DT` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( `ACCNO` )
);
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b0cf8)